# What is the best practice for working on a shared excel add-in?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

Currently we have a shared excel add-in created in-house and stored on a shared server. However if I want to make changes to this, everyone who has the macro installed has to close excel even if they aren't using the macro currently. Even on a small team this is difficult to accomplish.

Is there a way that I can make changes on a draft/beta/development version and "push" those changes to the main file?

Many thanks!

Comment: One option: Give your users read-only access to that network share (so the file is not blocked and opened in read-only mode). Option 2: Give every user a individual copy of that add-in into his default add-in folder by publishing it via group policies from your server. • In any case your users need to restart Excel to make changes work (no workaround for this). • Another probably helpful ressource: [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish).

Comment: We did something similar, where every time the macro was called it went and checked its ID number with that on the server - if the server version was newer it would download the new version and then continue ie it was self-updating...

Comment: Thanks! Upon looking into the file permissions further, we need to fix the user groups first. More users should be moved to the read only group, or a new group created.